# How to add product attributes at admin dashboard bestsellers tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, admin-panel, dashboard

I would like to know, how to add product attributes ie SKU, Color, Size at admin dashboard `bestsellers` tab?

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Dashboard\Tab\Products\Ordered.php
```

**Collection Code:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
            ->setModel('catalog/product')
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
        ;
```

[image: Tab screenshot from admin dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `->join('catalog/product', 'product_id = entity_id', '*')` to Collection Code.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_bestsellers_collection')
            ->setModel('catalog/product')
            ->join('catalog/product', 'product_id = entity_id', '*')
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
```

Then create SKU Column.

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'index'     => 'sku',
            'type'      => 'string',
            'sortable'  => false
        ));
```